# Checking a series of coin tosses for a sequence of 3 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script that flips a coin untill either "heads" is flipped 3 times in a row, or " tails"  is flipped 3 times in a row.

My attempt is a quite long snippet of code that does not do what I want it to do. It simply prints out "heads"  once and loops on forever:

```
import random

cointosses = []
total_count = 0

while total_count >= 0:
    tosses = random.randint(1,2)
    total_count += 1
    if tosses == 1:
        cointosses.append("heads")
    if tosses == 2:
        cointosses.append("tails")
    print(cointosses)
    seq_counter1 = 0
    seq_counter2 = 0
    total_seq = 0
    while total_seq <= 3:
        check1 = "heads"
        check2= "tails"
        for toss in cointosses:
            if toss == check1:
                seq_counter1 +=1 
                seq_counter2 = 0
                if seq_counter1 == 3:
                    total_seq = 3
                    break
            if toss == check2:
                seq_counter1 = 0
                seq_counter2 +=1
                if seq_counter2 == 3:
                    total_seq = 3
                    break

    if total_seq == 3:
        break
```

I'm sure there is some much simpler way of doing this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do never leave your `while` loop that checks your list. The `break` statements only leaves the `for`-loop (setting `total_seq = 3`) - your `while` loops until `total_seq` is *greater* then 3 -> **endless loop**:

> ```
> while total_seq <= 3:        # this is never been left because <= 3
>     check1 = "heads"         #                                 ^^ smaller equal
>     check2= "tails"
>     for toss in cointosses:
>         if toss == check1:
>             seq_counter1 +=1 
>             seq_counter2 = 0
>             if seq_counter1 == 3:
>                 total_seq = 3
>                 break              # breaks out of the for but total_seq = 3 so in while
>         if toss == check2:
>             seq_counter1 = 0
>             seq_counter2 +=1
>             if seq_counter2 == 3:
>                 total_seq = 3
>                 break              # breaks out of the for but total_seq = 3 so in while
> ```

---

You can simplify your code a *lot* by simply adding to the list and checking if the *last 3 elements are equal* instead of checking *the whole list* every time:

```
import random

def toss():
    """Return randomly 'heads' or 'tails'."""
    return "heads" if (random.randint(1,2) == 1) else "tails"

# need at least 3 tosses to finish
cointosses = []
for _ in range(3):
    cointosses.append(toss())
    print(cointosses)

# repeat until the set(..) of the last 3 elements contains exactly 1 item 
while not len(set(cointosses[-3:]))==1:
    cointosses.append(toss())
    print(cointosses)

print(f"It took {len(cointosses)} tosses to get 3 equal ones.")
```

Output 2 runs:

```
['tails']
['tails', 'tails']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'heads']
It took 5 tosses to get 3 equal ones.

['tails']
['tails', 'tails']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads', 'tails']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads', 'tails', 'tails']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads', 'tails', 'tails', 'heads']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails', 'heads', 'tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', ... snipp ..., 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', 'tails']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', ... snipp ..., 'heads', 'heads', 'tails', 'tails']
['tails', 'tails', 'heads', 'heads', ... snipp ..., 'heads', 'tails', 'tails', 'tails']
It took 13 tosses to get 3 equal ones.
```

If you dislike `set()` you could also check:

```
while not all(i == cointosses[-1] for i in cointosses[-3:-1]):
    # rest identical
```

Doku:

- [set() and frozenset()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)
- [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)
- [python built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) - Overview, the alternate approach uses [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

Answer (score 1):

## There are a few problems regarding this code:

### 1. This code produces an infinite loop:

The inner while loop only terminates **if the variable total_seq contains a value greater than 3**. Since the only values that could possibly be assigned to it **are 0 and 3** *(according to your code)*, this while loop will go on forever.

```
...
total_seq = 0 #<-----------------------
while total_seq <= 3:
    ...
    for toss in cointosses:
        if toss == check1:
            ...
            if seq_counter1 == 3:
                total_seq = 3 #<-----------------------
                break
        if toss == check2:
            ...
            if seq_counter2 == 3:
                total_seq = 3 #<-----------------------
                break
...
```

### 2. You only coinflip once at the beginning and that use this result over and over again

random.randint(...) gives you one value which is stored in the cointosses list *(which means: you only flip the coin once)*. **The inner for loop** assumes however, that you have a large number of tosses already stored in the list. It only sets total_seq to 3 **if it can find 3 consecutive coinflips**.

Otherwise it will just repeat the inner while loop and do the same thing again without adding new coinflips *(outer while is never reached again)*

```
tosses = random.randint(1,2)
...
if tosses == 1:
    cointosses.append("heads")
if tosses == 2:
    cointosses.append("tails")
...
    for toss in cointosses:
        ...
            if seq_counter1 == 3:
                total_seq = 3
                break
        ...
            if seq_counter2 == 3:
                total_seq = 3
                break
...
```

### 3. The sequence counters **seq_counter1 and seq_counter2** will only reset if the previous coinflip had a different result.

Since you only coinflip once *(as discussed in problem 2)* the "previous coinflip" is always just the first one you did.
This means that you coinflip once at the beginning and either increment seq_counter1 or seq_counter2 to 3 depending on the result of that first flip.

```
...
seq_counter1 = 0
seq_counter2 = 0
...
while total_seq < 3:
    ...
        if toss == check1:
            seq_counter1 +=1
            seq_counter2 = 0
            ...
        if toss == check2:
            seq_counter1 = 0
            seq_counter2 +=1
            ...
...
```

## Solution

All three problems can be solved by removing the inner while loop and simply execute its code in the outer one:

```
import random
cointosses = []
total_count = 0
while total_count >= 0:
    tosses = random.randint(1,2)
    total_count += 1
    if tosses == 1:
        cointosses.append("heads")
    if tosses == 2:
        cointosses.append("tails")
    print(cointosses)
    seq_counter1 = 0
    seq_counter2 = 0
    total_seq = 0
    check1 = "heads"
    check2= "tails"
    for toss in cointosses:
        if toss == check1:
            seq_counter1 +=1
            seq_counter2 = 0
            if seq_counter1 == 3:
                total_seq = 3
                break
        if toss == check2:
            seq_counter1 = 0
            seq_counter2 +=1
            if seq_counter2 == 3:
                total_seq = 3
                break

    if total_seq == 3:
        break
```

This works because the condition **total_seq == 3** is already tested by the last if statement in the outer loop.

## Conclusion

This code however is not verry perfomant since you build a list and iterate over it again and again.
You are iterating over everything every time you append one cointoss. However if you think about it: You only need to check if the newly appended element creates a consecutive row.

If you want to do this right, you should do it with only one loop *(no nested loops)* :)